# Change background of the parent div when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my template where radio button is selected when its wrapping/parent div is clicked.

Additionally I'm  trying to change the background color  to `red` and text color to `white` of the selected radio option.

If the radio option is unchecked reset its background color to default `white` and text color to `black`.

But with my code background and text of all select option is set to background color  to `white` and text color to `black`.

How can I set option's background color to default `white` and text color to `black` if other option is selected.

Both Jquery and javascript approach is appreciated. Thanks.

```js
$('.selectRadio').click(function(event) {
  /* console.log($('.selectRadio').length) */
  ;
  let element = $('.selectRadio');
  let radButton = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');
  for (let i = 0; i <= element.length; i++) {
    /* $('selector').index(this) */
    if (element.index(this) - 1 == i) {
      console.log(element.index(this) - 1);
      console.log(i);
      radButton.prop("checked", true);
      radButton.parent().css("background-color", "red");
      radButton.parent().css("color", "white");
    } else {
      radButton.parent().css("background-color", "unset");
      radButton.parent().css("color", "unset");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" >Option 1</label>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a lot more complex that it needs to be. Simplify it by putting the 'active' state CSS rules in to a class
which you add/remove based on the state of the checkbox. Note that you should use the `change` event handler when dealing with radio and checkbox inputs.

```js
let $containers = $('.radio');
$containers.find(':radio').on('change', e => {
  $containers.removeClass('active'); // remove from all containers
  $(e.target).closest('.radio').addClass('active'); // add class to current
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #F00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" />
          Option 1
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optradio">
          Option 2
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optradio">
          Option 3
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's also worth noting that you can achieve a very similar effect using CSS alone by moving the radio button outside of the `label`:

```css
.radio :checked + label {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="opt1" />          
        <label for="opt1">Option 1</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="opt2" />          
        <label for="opt2">Option 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="opt3" />          
        <label for="opt3">Option 3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to select radio button when user clicks on `.selectRadio` div

Comment: Why? Replace the `.selectRadio` div with a `label` element that wraps the radio input and you get that behaviour for free, without the need for any JS code at all

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the `radioButton` again within the for loop and invert the if logic to something like below code snippet.

```js
$('.selectRadio').click(function(event) {
  let element = $('.selectRadio');
  let radButton = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');
  radButton.parent().css("background-color", "red");
  radButton.parent().css("color", "white");
  for (let i = 0; i <= element.length; i++) {
    let radButton = $(element[i]).find('input[type=radio]');
    if (element.index(this) !== i) {
      console.log(element.index(this));
      radButton.parent().css("background-color", "white");
      radButton.parent().css("color", "red");
    } else {
      radButton.prop("checked", true);
      radButton.parent().css("background-color", "red");
      radButton.parent().css("color", "white");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" >Option 1</label>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 selectRadio">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```